# Windows 8 guest, ubuntu 12.10 host - sound will only play through front headphone jack

Tags: sound, virtualization, vmware, windows-8

I've had a search but couldn't find a solution for my issue.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with VMWare Player 5.0.1 build-894247.

Ubuntu is recognizing my sound card as a "Creative Labs CA0106 Soundblaster" and sound functions as you would expect from within.  (Sound plays from main speakers with no issues).

Within VMWare I've got a new copy of Windows 8 Enterprise with VMWare Tools installed, the sound card gets detected and the guest reports no issues with hardware.

At this point I noticed I'm not getting any sound from within the VM, I've been scratching my head for hours until I thought to try headphones in the front jack on the computer.

*It turns out that sound has been working all along from within Windows 8 / VMWare however for some reason it is "playing" through the front headphone jack regardless of if it is in use or not.*

Has anyone else come across a similar issue or does anyone have any advise on how to resolve this?

Many thanks!
J

**tl;dr** - sound from win 8 guest plays through headphone jack instead of speakers